# PowerShell 5.1: Make a function available to used module

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

I have a script that provides a little management interface by running a miniature web server in PowerShell using the `System.Net.HttpListener` object. It "uses" 4 modules (`*.psm1` files) with the `Use Module <module name>` directives at the top of the file. There is a common function called `Read-Html` in the web server script that needs to be available for the modules to use. On an older version of PowerShell (I don't remember the version but I'm certain it was at least 4.2) on a different computer this code worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to make a small update and PowerShell complains that `Read-Html` cannot be found with a `CommandNotFoundException`. The web server script does not have classes, but in the module files all of the code is in classes. When functionality from a module is needed, the web server script instantiates the relevant class. The `Read-Html` function is declared before any of the modules' classes are instantiated.

Here is a sample of some code that instantiates a class and reads from it (this is one of several entries in a `switch` block) `ComputerProfle` is the class name from the module:

```
      "GET /computer"{
        if($parameters.Count -gt 1){
          [ComputerProfile] $theProfile = [ComputerProfile]::new($databasePath, $parameters)
          $html = $theProfile.getHtml()
          $theProfile.cleanup()
        }
        else {
          $html = (Read-Html "computer.html" $navHash)
        }
      }
```

The `Read-Html` function works as expected here. Inside the module, `Read-Html` is called to load an HTML template that is filled with info then returned by the `getHtml()` method. However, when called inside the module, PowerShell throws a `CommandNotFoundException` exception:

```
Read-Html : The term 'Read-Html' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\fake\project\path\modules\computer.psm1:203 char:40
+                             $posts += (Read-Html "post-body.html" $po ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Read-Html:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I make the `Read-Html` function available to the modules?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the `Read-Html` function (a couple others) to a new file called `commons.psm1` and importing that with `Use Module` wherever it is needed. Works exactly how I need it to.